# Unicorn master memory increasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, memory-management, unicorn

I have a ruby service running with unicorn which spawns 20 child worker. When I start my service, unicorn master starts with approx 520 MB of memory and then master spawn 20 child worker. My service runs perfectly for 7-8 day, but gradually unicorn master memory is kept increasing and goes up to 1.3 GB, which apparently is causing OOM error when unicorn master trying to fork a new child (which now need 1.3 GB of memory to fork new child)and due to increased memory footprint, memory was not available.

**So my concern here is,**

- As per my understanding, Unicorn master doesn't serve any request, its
  sole purpose is to spawn missing child then why master process memory is increasing?
- I have unicorn-worker-killer configured with my app which is working absolutely
  fine. If there is any memory leak in my Ruby app then unicorn-worker-killer should already be handling it. Is this assumption wrong? Can there be any memory leak in master process due to my Ruby app?
- After killing the child worker, the unicorn is creating new child worker process with memory approx same as master process. Is it true that all child worker which Unicorn master will create over the time will start with the same memory as Unicorn master process?

Here below is my service and machine configuration.

**Ruby**: 2.1.2

**Unicorn**: 4.6.3

**Unicorn worker count**: 20

**OS**: Debian GNU/Linux 8, Jessie

**RAM**: 24 GB

Comment: Are you using ["Unicorn"](https://bogomips.org/unicorn/) or ["Unicron"](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Unicron)? You're randomly flipping between the two spellings.

Comment: Sorry for typo, its Unicorn. I have updated question.

Comment: If you can't circumscribe your issue to some source code I can hardly find out how someone could help you. Anyway, it's very likely that you have a memory leak in your application code or in a dependency.

Comment: You seem to have some kind of memory leak on your libraries. That being said, you should test each of your dependencies for memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks all for your response. I agree that there can be a memory leak in my app. But it should impact only child workers processes, not master process. I am not able to understand why my master process memory is increasing.

Comment: @mdesantis: I tried to collect GC stat and Objectspace size for unicorn master process. Here below are links for log dump:

**Objectspace size:**  

 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HYgitNhW1PDECfnRpxnqyRt_rblov2Xp  

**GC stat:**  

 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YVuCG6Mh8UJOYa72n8F4cEadi0QnGvTw

Comment: From dump, I can deduce that Object space size is continuously increasing, which is indicating a memory leak in my Ruby app. But I am not able to understand why Major GC count is always fix. Does it mean major GC is not running? Any reason for the same?